# jQuery function on different Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

So, I have a simple code that I can't get it to work. I tried to find answers on the same topic here, but being new to jQuery all answers seem too complicated.

Anyways, what I want to do is have the same script run for different divs. After some reading here I managed to arrange the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<div id="mydiv1" onclick="handleClick(this)" style="position:relative; left:0px;">Div One</div>
<div id="mydiv1a" style="position:relative; left:0px;">Div One A</div>

<div id="mydiv2" onclick="handleClick(this)" style="position:relative; left:0px;">Div Two</div>
<div id="mydiv2a" style="position:relative; left:0px;">Div Two A</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

function handleClick(x) {
 $(x.id + 'a').fadeToggle("slow");
}

}
</script>
```

What I want this to do is when I click #mydiv1, the function should run on #mydiv1a. And the same for #mydiv2. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to assign the handling within your script (not inline in html). Bonus for that is that you can use jQuery delegation, i.e. assign a click handler on the document body for a number of elements within the body. Furthermore, the styling should be in a css tag/css file where possible ([**why?**](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/20/decoupling-html-from-css/)). In this case both `position` and `left` are useless. The snippet shows all this:

```js
$('body').on('click', '#mydiv1, #mydiv2', handleClick);
// ^ handler on body  |                   |
//                    for elements        |
//                                        handler method

function handleClick(e) {
  $('#'+this.id+'a').fadeToggle('slow');
}
```

```css
#mydiv1, #mydiv2 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div id="mydiv1">Div One</div>
<div id="mydiv1a">Div One A</div>

<div id="mydiv2">Div Two</div>
<div id="mydiv2a">Div Two A</div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer as it also points out ways to improve the code substantially. Separation of concerns is important, man.

Comment: Thank you KooiInc! Seems to work great now!
Yes I have the scripts in different files within the server, not inline in the html. I just wrote it this way so I can give a simple picture of what I want. I left some useless stuff in though.
Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `#` which is how you select element with a specific id in jQuery or css for that matter

```
$('#' + x.id + 'a').fadeToggle("slow");
```

But you can simplify your code to the below

```
$('div').filter(function(){ return /\d+$/.test(this.id) }).click(function(){
   $(this).next().fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: `$('div[id] + div[id$=a]')` isn't relevant selector, you are binding click event on `div[id$=a]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(this).next().fadeToggle("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

This code creates a `click` event for both `div`s. The event will be aware of the specific `div` clicked.

```
$(function(){

    $("#mydiv1, #mydiv2").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeToggle("slow");
    });

});
```